# What is getservbyname() — do I understand it right?

Tags: c, sockets, port

I don't really know what to write in the first parameter of [`getservbyname()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getservbyname.html).
I read that if I give the name and protocol such as TCP I get a struct back with information to the server, but what should I write in there?

So, for example, `getservbyname("www.google.com", "tcp")`

This is wrong but what needs to be in the first parameter to get, for example, the port from Google or other websites or am I understanding this absolutely wrong?

Answer (score 7):

`getservbyname` looks up service names from [this list](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) and gives you back port numbers. "http" is an example of a service name that you can look up in this table.

`www.google.com` is a *host* name, not a service name. `gethostbyname` looks up host names and gives you IPv4 addresses; to connect to Google's web server you need its address *as well as* the service's port number. Nowadays it is usually better to do both lookups at once, using [`getaddrinfo`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html), which also seamlessly handles IPv6.

Answer (score 3):

"www.google.com" is a *hostname*, not a service.  `getservbyname()` is just a fancy way to read information from the `/etc/services` file on your local machine, so the first argument to the function might be something like "telnet" or "ftp".  i.e. it is used to find out what port a particular service is expected to be running on, *on your local machine*.

If you want to get information about a hostname (e.g. its IP address), you can get that via a different API call like [gethostbyname()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html), or (for a more modern/flexible implementation) [getaddrinfo()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html).

Comment: `getservbyname` and `gethostbyname` are both deprecated, thread-unsafe, and IPv6-incompatible. You should **always** replace them with `getaddrinfo`.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Deprecated?  I can't even find 'em in [POSIX 7 at all](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).  They're gone officially.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Yes, they were deprecated in the previous version and gone in the current one. But they're still present in implementations, where they should be considered deprecated (present for compat with old software, but not for new use).